# ffmpeg - create blank video file with multichannel audio?

Tags: ffmpeg

i found a couple of threads on stackoverflow that allow me to create a dummy mov file for picture:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x480 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv422p10 -t 10 output_proreshq.mov
```

the above creates a 10 second, picture-only file.

this:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=5.1:sample_rate=48000 -t 10 output.wav
```

creates a 6 channel wav file.

i haven't been able to figure out how to combine these two commands to create a file with blank picture and six channels of blank audio. can someone show me how to get this done? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Combined command is:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x480 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=5.1:sample_rate=48000 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv422p10 -c:a pcm_s16le -t 10 output_proreshq.mov
```

`-tune stillimage` is for libx264 only and is being ignored in your command so I removed it.

As for your duration queries, all of the simplified examples below will have a 10 second duration:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color -f lavfi -i anullsrc -t 10 output.mov
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=d=10 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -shortest output.mov
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color -t 10 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -shortest output.mov
ffmpeg -t 10 -f lavfi -i color -t 10 -f lavfi -i anullsrc output.mov
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color,trim=duration=10 -f lavfi -i anullsrc,atrim=duration=10 output.mov
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color,trim=duration=10 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -shortest output.mov
```

Use whatever method you prefer.

Comment: thanks! looks like you substituted d=10 for my -t 10. does that matter? (all of the examples i saw used -t 10.) also, i see you're using 'shortest' at the end. is that necessary? what's the significance here? thanks again.

Comment: @BabaG Makes no difference. You can use d=10 with shortest, or just -t 10. I edited it to be more like your originals.

Comment: so, d=10 would normally be used with shortest but -t 10 would not? iow, shortest is normally used in conjunction with d=? trying to get the syntax convention straight in my mind.

Comment: @BabaG ffmpeg will not by default stop at the shortest input. So if using inputs with infinite duration you either have to 1) use `-t` as an output option as you did, or 2) declare the duration of the input(s) via `-t` as an input option, using `d` if supported by the filter, or by using another filter such as (t)rim/(a)select. 3) `-shortest` can be used if one input has a finite duration and one does not.